# How to write this exception in Python 2.6

Tags: python, exception

I need to write an expection that if a string is null, then fire this exception. How to write this?

Eg. 
str = get_str()

if get_str() returns None or nothing. It should raise an exception.

Comment: probably you may use `raise ValueError("Input cannot be Null")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returning None (which is the same as not returning anything explicitly) isn't an exception by itself. If it should be an exception, get_str() should raise this exception, and it's up to you to decide what the correct reason and therefore correct exception is. It may be ValueError, TypeError or something custom. E.g.

```
def get_str():
  x = some_complex_computation()
  if x is None:
    raise ValueError("because it's wrong!!")
  return x
```

However, often, None will be a valid return value. Either check it explicitly once you get the return value as Ignacio points out, or just use "duck typing": assume you get a string back and let python fail if it isn't. E.g.

```
  str = get_str()
  if 'foo' in str:
    print "Looks okay!"
```

if str is None, python will fail at the 'in' expression with a TypeError exception.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "nothing" in Python. There is either something, or there is not.

```
if str is None:
  raise SomeException()
```

Comment: Could we use some kind of built-in exceptions?

Comment: Absolutely. But it may make sense to use a custom exception.

Comment: @user469652: which one would you like: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions `ValueError` looks fine to me.

Comment: Depending on the situation, `TypeError` might also be appropriate.

Comment: None is Python's nothing, yet None is something; therefore, in Python, nothing is something.